# QPushButton Default State

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The dialog window has three widgets: QComboBox, QLineEdit and QPushButton.
When dialog is shown the QLineEdit is being set as "current" by default. Any keyboard entry performed will be entered straight into QLineEdit field.

Instead of QLineEdit I want QPushButton to be current. So the user could hit a keyboard "Enter" key to trigger the function connected to QPushButton. What flag or attribute of QPushButton needs to be set to achieve this?

Comment: At a wild guess you could try changing the tab order, or fiddle with focus, e.g. `setFocusPolicy` to prevent that widget automatically gaining focus.

Comment: You can try to change the initialization order. Or `setTabOrder(widget1, widget2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using QtDesigner, with QPushButton selected go to *Property Editor* and scroll to the bottom, set the *Default* property checked OR inside your code, `button.setDefault(True)`, this feature is specially for what you are looking for. Look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, You want to use `eventFilter()` to handle `keyPressEvent()`. Then You only need

```
    self.pushButton.setFocus()
```

in QDialog's constructor and install an appropriate eventFilter on pushButton